# TextBlock Text property still null after adding Inlines

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

In a very simple WPF application, I have the following code in the `button1_click()` method:

```
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run("TextBlock is designed to be lightweight."));
canvas.Children.Add(textBlock1);
Debug.Print("textBlock1.Text: {0}", textBlock1.Text);
```

The `Debug.Print` statement prints nothing for the `Text` property, but the actual text (i.e. "TextBlock is designed...") is visible in the `TextBlock` control on the canvas.  Why doesn't the `Text` property depict an exact copy of the `Inlines`?

PS: There is no data binding, etc. used.  The project is very simple, with a TextBlock and a Button on a Canvas inside MainWindow, and minimal XAML; everything is handled in the code-behind.

Comment: I can only suggest that when you add **TextBlock.Inlines** manually, the changes are not reflected on the **TextBlock.Text** property. But if you try to specify the **TextBlock.Text** property, **TextBlock.Inlines** collection will be correctly modified.

Answer (score 3):

You can just directly set the `Text` property of the `Textblock`. If you have a text that needs special formatting like **bold,** *italic*, underline, etc in for each words then that's the time you want to use the `Inlines`.

If you want to debug the actual `Text` you want to extract the `Run` into a separate variable and access its `Text` property.

```
var run = new Run("TextBlock is designed to be lightweight");
Debug.Print(run.Text);
```

Comment: Yes, setting the `Text` property directly works.  I wasn't aware that a `Run` had a `Text` property in turn, so that was good to know.  Can we say then that the moral of the story is to only resort to `Inlines` in case of special formatting needs?

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes only use it if you want to say just bold the first character and the rest is normal text then you create two runs where one has bold formatting.

Comment: @Sabuncu For example, we have used **TextBlock.Inlines** in order to highlight the substring (search query) of text in **TextBlock**.